# Labels Added via Button Command Not Expanding Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to dynamically add labels to a frame contained within a canvas, for scrollbar capability. The labels are being added via a function that is called from a button. The function works fine if called on startup, the frame updates as expected and I have scrollbar capabilities. If I call the function from the button command the frame updates with the labels, but only up to the limit of the starting frame/canvas size. The additional area of the frame containing the rest of the labels won't be visible as the scrollbar isn't "activated"

I tried searching but couldn't find this question being asked before. I am new to Python and Tkinter so apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("550x550")

main_frame = Frame(root)
main_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

button_frame = Frame(root)
button_frame.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

image_canvas_0 = Canvas(main_frame, height = 500, width = 500)
image_canvas_0.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

image_canvas_0_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient = VERTICAL, command = image_canvas_0.yview)
image_canvas_0_scrollbar.grid(column = 1, row = 0, sticky = (N,S))

image_canvas_0.config(yscrollcommand = image_canvas_0_scrollbar.set)
image_canvas_0.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: image_canvas_0.configure(scrollregion = image_canvas_0.bbox("all")))

second_frame = Frame(image_canvas_0)
image_canvas_0.create_window((0,0), window = second_frame, anchor = 'nw')

def test_function(*args):
    for i in range(100):
        label_text = 'test' + str(i)
        Label(second_frame, text = label_text).grid(row = i, column = 0)

func_button = Button(button_frame, text = 'Click Me', command = test_function)
func_button.grid(row = 0, column =  0)

#test_function()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would be best if you could create an example that didn't rely on images.

Comment: Agreed, you should post a [mre]

Comment: You should also verify that the widgets are going on the row and column you think they are. I don't think they are. You seem to keep adding the labels to the same five rows. A single print statement will answer this question for you.

Comment: Ok thanks guy, I simplified the code as much as I think is possible and edited the original post to reflect the changes. The issue persists with just labels that contain text. The function isn't supposed to add an additional 5 (or 100 now) rows each time you click. The first click is the only one that matters for the demonstration. Just trying to compare and contrast button click vs. function run on startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't changing the `scrollregion` after you've added widgets to the frame. The canvas doesn't know that there's new data that should be scrollable.

Normally this is done by adding a bind to the frame's `<Configure>` event, since that event fires whenever the frame changes size.

```
second_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: image_canvas_0.configure(scrollregion = image_canvas_0.bbox("all")))
```

The reason your code seems to work when calling the function directly at startup is that you have a similar binding on the canvas itself, which automatically fires once the widget is actually shown on the screen. That happens after you call `test_function()` when `mainloop` first starts to run. Once the program starts, the canvas `<Configure>` event doesn't fire a second time.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, that did it! Need to study up on bindings and lambdas some more. Thanks for all your other posts about tkinter as well, I'm learning a bunch from you.